# Unity- how to make object always face moving camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Ok this is what I’m trying to achieve - I have a cube that is in front of my camera. The camera is a magic window, so it’s rotates with the accelerometer. 
I’ve tried parenting the cube to the camera but the front face is not always facing the camera still. What do I need to do?

Diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Childing is a good first step for actually moving an object.

For rotation you can use [LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) on your cube

Answer (score 0):

I believen this is something you are looking for.

```
this.transform.LookAt(this.transform.position + mainCamera.transform.rotation * Vector3.forward,mainCamera.transform.rotation * Vector3.up);

this.transform.position = mainCamera.transform.position +mainCamera.transform.forward* 2;
```